# SQL Table partitioning

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I am working on a badly designed database in MS SQL 2008.  It has a table with "60,000,000" records and it increases by about "4,000,000" records per week.

So if I use "SQL 2008 table partitioning", will it help?  If so, please suggest the steps to follow.

Comment: If your row count is directly related to your bad database design, fixing that should be your top priority.

Comment: Does thsi table have indexing? Exactly what kind of help are you expecting to get? Better data integrity? Faster inserts, faster reports and selects? How is the data queried, do you have a good candidate for a partioning column?

Comment: Why you think a tiny table like that is badly designed? It is usual for many databases. I have a 14 day in production database here, with 800 million rows adding 40 million rows to a centtral table PER DAY and guess what - that is good design, we just add that many rows because have to. A billion rows is SMALL today on real server hardware (i.e. not mobile phone level).

Comment: Table has a clustered index. It is used quiet often. And its not a data warehouse. It will be helpful if any one suggest how i can partition that table.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of points you need to check before arriving at Table Partitioning Strategy

- Total Records "60,000,000" records and it increases by about "4,000,000" records per week
- Question - Can you Archive Remove any Data on Weekly basis. Reason is to know if you use queries for OLTP or OLAP you can think of having another machine where data is replicated and retained
- Do you know statics of how queries look like, Indexes that are being used
- Objective of partitioning is to reduce the number of partitioning to look for required data. Example - Suppose your query where clause filter is based on month number. Then in that case if you have parition done every month, then when you have a query for month = 5, then only that particular partition would be queried
- You have to provide little more information on schema, query usage patterns, indexes

Answer (score 2):

Help with *what*? You did not explain the problem. Are certain queries slow? Do you have problems with ETL? Do you have problems deletion of obsolete data? Do you have problems with maintenance and backups?

As a general rule table partitioning is a feature for easing ETL via [fast partition switch operations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160.aspx) and for data location administration (distribute tables across several filegroups and leverage filegroup features like [piece-meal restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177425.aspx)).

One area partitioning does **not** help is performance. Performance issues are addressed with indexes and the *best* you can hope for is on-par performance with a non-partitioned case. There is a misconception going around that [partition elimination](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2006/02/17/partition-elimination-in-sql-server-2005.aspx) will help performance, see also [Introduction to Partitioned Tables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/11/27/introduction-to-partitioned-tables.aspx). What is usually missed is that for performance a much much better alternative is to simply move the partitioning key as the leftmost  key in the clustered key, which will cause a range scan with, in the worse case, at least on-par, if not better, performance  than compared with the partition elimination. Partition elimination *helps queries that have to handle partitioned tables* when partitioning was required due to the other reasons (ETL, fast deletes, filegroup management).