# Does partitioning work with SQL Server 2005 Standard edition SP2

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-partitioning

I am using SQL Server 2005 Standard edition with SP2 in test environment. My local SQL Server is a Developer edition.

I was able to partition the table on my local computer. I know that the SQL Server Standard edition does not support either indexed views or partitioning. I just wanted to know if the SP2 has made any difference to the Standard edition.

Thanks
vihar.

Comment: No. A standard edition just doesn't support partioning - no matter what SP you apply to it.

Comment: To add to marcs's answer: use of partitioning also marks the database as a 'persisted SKU feature' and will prevent opening the database on standard/express/web edition, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280724.aspx

Comment: The main thing is I am trying to improve the performance of a huge table of 24Mn records. It is well indexed. I am using normal queries using basic inner joins and where conditions inside a stored procedure. How can I improve the performance of that queries.

Comment: Partitioning will not improve performance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126344/sql-table-partitioning/7261392#7261392. If you have problems with simple queries on a small table (24M is nowhere *near* huge) then for sure the table is not 'well indexed'. Post the exact tables schema and the queries that have problems. And also, do some proper investigation first to locate the performance problems. Follow http://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc966413

Comment: Hi Remus. This system is being used since 2005 and has been slow since then. The records keep on appending to this table. The table is clustered indexed on the identifier columns and non clustered indexed on the columns which are used in the conditions. I did my part of research and came to a conclusion that partitioning is not the solution for my problem. I am keen on using indexed views. Please suggest me if I am wrong. I am using functions right now. Am Trying to put the queries in the functs to the views and index them. Would that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partitioning doesn't supported in SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition neither it is not supported in Oracle Standard Edition.

This vendors want you to buy the expensive Enterprise Edition products, which also don't have partitions as default, you need to buy an extra feature which support partitions.

If your application is written in Jave there is a product called [Rewius](http://www.rewius.com) which might help to solve your solution, as far as I know it works as a proxy above the JdbcDriver and encapsulate the queries and the insert to the database and emulate the partitions feature on Standard Edition database, It is cheaper solution if you only need the partition feature and not other enterprise features.

Answer (score 0):

24M isn't huge but saying that partitioning wouldn't improve performance is a blanket statement; some cases no, some cases a little and some cases substantial performance increases. If you are using Standard, you can create your own partitioning by splitting the table and throwing a stored proc in front of it (or i guess you could do it in your app code but wouldn't recommend it). Of course things like how you are searching and what the data is would dictate how you split the table. Many will say otherwise but have been in the same boat when hardware limitations and processing power are boundaries and it most definitely makes a difference searching 2M rows vs 24M or 60M rows regardless of how great your indexing strategy is.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. We have implemented the indexed views to solve the issue with the performance. It is working great now. Thanks for all the help/

Answer (score 0):

We have implemented the indexed views to solve the issue with the performance. It is working great now. Thanks for all the help